# Where can I find a large collection of random chess positions?

Tags: books, websites, studies

Does anyone know where it is possible to find a large number of chess positions in PNG, JPEG or any other image format? Quality, colour, size does not matter. The only thing that matters is that I'd prefer there to be some distortions in the image (like images scanned from books). Here is an example of a chess position such as I am looking for:

[image: example of chess position]

I am creating a tool which converts an image of a position to the board representation, and for this reason I need to collect a lot of different positions. Up till now I am getting them from PDF books I have.

Comment: Daniel, is there anything wrong with an email address? This is not advertisement of any sort, I just hope that someone will be able to help me by providing samples for my classifier.

Comment: I suppose, since the whole point is the unknown distortion, generating them yourself is not an option? Since basically you seem to seek for different possible scanning blurs, I suggest collecting them from Google Images would have less of a bias than scanning them yourself (each time with the same image quality, book positionning, etc.) (I can try to expand that into an answer if you want.)

Comment: You are right. I can not use just one book to take the samples, because they all will be almost the same. I already have taken some different books and downloaded different pics from google, but I hoped that some other people would be able to help. I thought that because they will be from different countries, places etc the samples will be different

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way I can think of is to write your own scraper (say) in Python.
I'd use `beautifulsoup` and aim at several sites, including Google Images (within whatever limits they impose)

If you are familiar with Python, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257409/download-image-file-from-the-html-page-source-using-python) is all you really need.

Start with Google Images, chessbase.com, and then make a round of the numerous chess websites that have tons of position images that you can scrape.